# Combining Results of Two SQL in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to do something like this in Postgresql Procedure

```
Select * 
  into MyVar 
from Tab1 
Where <Somecondition> limit 14;

If Num_of_Records < 14 Then

  Append 
    Into MyVar 
  Select * 
  from Tab1 
  Where <Relaxedcondition> 
  limit 14 - Num_of_Records; 

End If;

return Myvar
```

What would be the best thing/approach to use ?

Comment: Your should be using `ORDER BY` if you plan to use `LIMIT`.  What happens if more than 14 records are returned?  Does nothing happen, or do we append 14 records?

Comment: If first query returns 14 records, we just return that. If first query returns less then 14 ( say 8 ) records, we want to append  14 - 8 = 6 records from relaxed logic.

Comment: How do you plan on using this function?

Comment: select getTop14Supplier(MyCityId);

Comment: I have given you a query below which should return what you want.  See if perhaps you can incorpoate it into your function.

Comment: This will work but MyRelaxedLogic is a heavy one, so I wanted it to use MyRelaxedLogic only if Logic 1 has falied to return the required number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

We can actually handle your logic using plain SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT 1 AS label, * FROM Tab1 WHERE <some condition> ORDER BY col LIMIT 14)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 2 AS label, * FROM Tab1 WHERE <relaxed condition>)
ORDER BY label
LIMIT 14;
```

This will return up to 14 records from the first query with more strict conditions.  Should it return less than 14, then the second query with relaxed conditions would be able to add records until the total reaches 14.

I do not have much experience writing Postgres functions, but the above query should work in a function as well.

**Edit:**

If you want to ensure that the second query only runs in the event that the first query returns fewer than 14 records, then we can refactor to this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS label, * FROM Tab1 WHERE <some condition> ORDER BY col LIMIT 14
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
UNION ALL
(SELECT 2, * FROM Tab1 WHERE <relaxed condition> AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte < 14))
ORDER BY label
LIMIT 14;
```

In this case, the second query would fail in the `WHERE` clause and would not even iterate should the first query return 14 or more records.

Comment: This will work but MyRelaxedLogic is a heavy one, so I wanted it to use MyRelaxedLogic only if Logic 1 has falied to return the required number of rows.

Comment: @AnujSharma I attempted an edit which might address your concerns.  I'm not too worried about the second query in any case.

Comment: Thanks. Let me test this approach.